# Angular Modal Gallery - Position gallery images

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement an image modal, however I am having several problems.

I want the first images to fill the entire large box (class drop) and the rest to be below that same box, as shown in the image.

I've tried everything, but in the array of images, I can not display only one, for example, present only the first :(

Is there any way to implement this?

Thank you !

**My StackBlitz**

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uytvnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop">
    <div class="abc">
    <!-- 1 Image here  -->
        <section>
            <ks-modal-gallery [id]="3" [modalImages]="imagesMixedSizes"></ks-modal-gallery>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="Upcard">
    <!-- 2,3,4,5 Images here !!!  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 imagesMixedSizes: Image[] = [
    new Image(0, {
      // modal
      img: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery/master/examples/systemjs/assets/images/gallery/pexels-photo-135230.png',

    }),
    new Image(1, {
      // modal
      img: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery/master/examples/systemjs/assets/images/gallery/pexels-photo-547115.jpeg'
    })]
```

**Image Problem/Explanation**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can split the variables into two. If that is an option.

Like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anexan

Or if you don't want to create a new variable unnecessarily, slice the same array:

Example :

```
<ks-modal-gallery [id]="3" [modalImages]="imagesMixedSizes.slice(0,1)"></ks-modal-gallery>

<ks-modal-gallery [id]="4" [modalImages]="imagesMixedSizes.slice(1)"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

Comment: This link is the same as in the post, I think you were wrong

Comment: Thanks for notifying about the Link @MikeLanders I forgot to fork the Stackblitz

Comment: I had not thought of that, in principle should work on my example. Thank you